# how can i make $(document).on('touchstart') function work on ipad?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply toggling the class when a specific button is clicked, when the user clicks outside document i then want to remove the class. This works fine if I change the event to click and test on desktop but on iPad nothing seems to happen. Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to make this work?

```
$shoppingIcon.on('click', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prev($productInfo).toggleClass('active');
    });

    $(document).on('touchstart', function() {
        $productInfo.removeClass('active');
    });​
```

Comment: put alerts on the click and touchstart events alert('click') .. 'touchstart', which one/ do they both fire eventually?

Comment: Don't you need a plugin for that like `addTouch`: http://code.google.com/p/rsslounge/source/browse/trunk/public/javascript/addtouch.js?r=115

Comment: What do you mean nothing, do you mean the toggleClass doesn't happen, or just the removeClass

Comment: hey the remove class doesnt happen